# ¿Qué implican las diferentes opciones de un git pull cuando las ramas han divergido?

Tags: git, git-pull

Tengo un proyecto con dos ramas: *master* y *develop*.

Los dos últimos *commits* en *develop*:

```
feat: Update baz
refactor: foo structure
```

Los dos últimos *commits* en *master*:

```
Merge pull request #13 from oricis/develop
refactor: foo structure
```

Me situo en *develop* y ejecuto:

```
git merge de master
git pull
```

Aparece:

```
ayuda: Las ramas se han divergido y hay que especificar cómo reconciliarlas.
ayuda: Se puede hacerlo ejecutando uno de los comandos siguiente antes del
ayuda: próximo pull:
ayuda: 
ayuda:   git config pull.rebase false  # fusionar
ayuda:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebasar
ayuda:   git config pull.ff only       # solo avance rápido
...
```

La tercera opción a su vez muestra:

```
ayuda: Diverging branches can't be fast-forwarded, you need to either:
ayuda: 
ayuda:  git merge --no-ff
ayuda: 
ayuda: or:
ayuda: 
ayuda:  git rebase
```

*Git v.2.43.0 + repositorio Github.*
[Documentación de Git pull (EN).](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Answer (score 0):

Si hay divergencia es *imposible* hacer `fast-forward`. Fast forward solo es posible hacerlo si se está parado en un ancestro de la rama que se está tratando de mezclar..... Por ejemplo:

```
* eee (rama2)
* ddd
* ccc (rama1)
* bbb
* aaa
```

En este caso si se hace:

```
git checkout rama1
git merge rama2
```

git (que es vaguísimo) va a evitar hacer un merge y va a *correr* el apuntador de `rama1` a donde está `rama2` y así evita tener que crear un commit nuevo *"innecesario"*:

```
* eee (rama2, rama1 -> HEAD)
* ddd
* ccc
* bbb
* aaa
```

En este caso, por cierto, estoy usando una historia *lineal* para simplificar, pero un `fast-forward` se puede hacer también en historias con múltiples ramas paralelas.... La única restricción es que se esté parado en un ancestro de la rama que se quiere mezclar. Si **no** se está en un ancestro, no se puede hacer `fast-forward`.

Si las ramas han divergido, por ejemplo:

```
* eee (rama2)
* ddd
| * ccc (rama1)
| * bbb
|/
* aaa
```

Se puede ver qué `rama1` **no** está apuntando a un ancestro de `rama2` así que hacer un `fast-forward` es imposible. Hay que hacer bien merge o rebase.

La opción `pull.rebase` en `false` implica que *por defecto* (si no específicas lo contrario al llamar a `git pull` con `--rebase`), git debería hacer un merge al hacer `git pull`:

```
git checkout rama1
git pull rama2
```

Te quedaría esto:

```
* fff (rama1 -> HEAD)
|\
* | eee (rama2)
* | ddd
| * ccc
| * bbb
|/
* aaa
```

Si por el contrario, `pull.rebase` está puesto en `true`, entonces se hace un rebase *por defecto* al hacer `git pull` y quedaría esto:

```
* ccc' (rama1 -> HEAD)
* bbb'
* eee (rama2)
* ddd
* aaa
```